# How do I make packages without version numbers work in Swift Playgrounds on the iPad?

Tags: git, github, ipad, swift-playground, swift-package

I‘m trying to import the Swift package https://github.com/demharusnam/SwiftUIDrag into the playgrounds app on the iPad, but it won‘t work. I suspect it might have something to do with missing version tags, but I‘m new to git and thus don’t know how to add them or otherwise solve my problem. I hope somebody knows more about this topic.

Edit: I‘m experiencing a problem, where it says it checks the version, but then doesn’t give me the option to add it to the project.
I paste the link and tap enter.
[directly after pressing enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lhHO.jpg)
Then it „checks the version“ (in German), but doesn’t give me the option to add it.
[at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAl8H.jpg)
And then I’ve included a screenshot by hacking with swift to show what it should look like.
[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWUAI.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Specifically_, what does "won't work" mean? Please read [ask].